# How do I synchronize field properties with the database properties?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, oracle-spatial

I have a feature class with a property that is out of sync with the database table. The field property is "Allow NULL values" and it's currently set to "No". Earlier today, before I was aware of this setting in the feature class field properties, I deleted the "IS NOT NULL" constraint on the database table. The database table says this column should accept NULL values but the FC, when viewing in ArcMap, says NULL values are not allowed.

How do I synchronize the FC and database? Is there a metadata table somewhere that needs to be refreshed? Is there a better way to change the field property?

Comment: What database are you using?  Removing the constraint may not change the the database's NOT NULL setting.

Comment: @Vince Oracle 11g...

Comment: I think GDB_FieldInfo also has these constraints listed, that may be SDE_FieldInfo or similar. I would back up your database before mucking around in the back end, it's too easy to cause irreparable damage.

Comment: Please *edit* the question to include the exact Oracle release.